# Segue must be modal with page navigation

Tags: storyboard, segue, watchkit, uistoryboardsegue, apple-watch

I'm developing an app for Apple Watch that there is a scene with a table. When I select a row it pushes another scene perfectly. However when I added another scene and created the relationship of next scene with the first one the rows stopped working.I had to change the transition from push to modal and it worked again.
My question is: is it the right behaviour? or is it a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page-based navigation and hierarchical navigation are exclusive – you can't mix and match unless you present a new interface modally. This is expected behaviour.